# Grails making URL free for all

Tags: grails, spring-security

I need my url to be public access in `/api/test/blabla`, which return me a JSON. But I can't access the url because it keeps me returning to `/login/auth` and/or if I login the warning message is `sorry, you're not authorized to view this page`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/'              : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/smart/**'   : ['permitAll'],
    '/index'         : ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp'     : ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**'     : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**'      : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**'     : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**'  : ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico': ['permitAll']
]

grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = '/'
grails.app.context = "/"
```

I tried to to add new staticRules, but no success.

```
'/api/test/*'  : ['permitAll'],
```

My UrlMapping is like this:

```
"/api/test/$code" {
    controller = "testRest"
    action = [POST: "create", PUT: "update", GET: "get"]
}
```

And my method/class has no `@Secured` annotation. There's any way to make the url free for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 2.X of the Spring Security plugin, URLs are inaccessible by default. To make URLs publicly accessible by default, add the following to `Config.groovy`

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
```

However, before you make this change, you should be sure to understand the implications, at a minimum, [read this](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/single.html#requestMappings).